# Parse and remove part of a QString

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, qt, qstring

I want to parse some kind (or pure) XML code from a QString.

My QString is like:

```
<a>cat</a>My cat is very nice.
```

I want to obtain 2 strings:

**cat**, and **My Cat is very nice.**

I think a XML parser is not maybe necessary, but in the future I will have more tags in the same string so it's also a very interesting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Qt you have the [`QRegExp`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qregexp.html#details) class that can help you to parse your QString.

According to Documentation example:

```
 QRegExp rxlen("^<a>(.*)</a>(.*)$");
 int pos = rxlen.indexIn("<a>cat</a>My cat is very nice.");
 QStringList list
 if (pos > -1) {
     list << = rxlen.cap(1); // "cat"
     list << = rxlen.cap(2); // "My cat is very nice."
 }
```

The QStringList list will contain the `cat` and `My cat is very nice.`

Comment: I read the documentation, but could you give me a simple example like boost example with QRegExp? Thanks!

Comment: It would be something like  str = "Nokia Corporation\tqt.nokia.com\tNorway";
 QString company, web, country;
 rx.setPattern("^([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)\t([^\t]+)$");
 if (rx.indexIn(str) != -1) {
     company = rx.cap(1);
     web = rx.cap(2);
     country = rx.cap(3);
 }

?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression `<a>(.*)</a>(.*)`.

If you use `Boost` you could implement it like follows:

```
boost::regex exrp( "^<a>(.*)</a>(.*)$" );
boost::match_results<string::const_iterator> what;
if( regex_search( input_string, what, exrp ) ) {
    std::string tag( what[1].first, what[1].second );
    std::string value( what[2].first, what[2].second );
}
```

Comment: input_string can be a QString?

Comment: I'm not sure. But you can get `std::string` from `QString` by using [`QString::toStdString`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qstring.html#toStdString) method.